# Testing: spyOn new Object in Class Constructor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jasmine

I have a React component as such:

```
class Entity extends React.component{
  constructor(props{
  ...
  const foo = new Bar(...);
  }
  ...
}
module.exports = Entity;
```

I am now using Jasmine 2.5 to write tests for this module, and I am wondering how to check that the `foo` object was created.

Comment: [You might find this useful](http://sinonjs.org/)

Comment: assign `foo` to `this` (this.foo = new Bar()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it. The obvious solution was to use
`this.foo = new Bar(...);`
instead of
`const foo = ...`.

Then in my tests, I declared a wrapper:
`this.wrapper = enzyme.shallow(<Entity ... />);`

and then could run my test as usual:

`expect(this.wrapper.instance().foo).toBeTruthy;`